# Rasa x fails to bind to PORT on heroku app

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, rasa, rasa-x

I have dockerized my rasa x chatbot and deployed it in heroku, but the application keeps on crashing.

`Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

My docker files looks like :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENTRYPOINT []
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip && python3 -m pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip==20.2 && python3 -m pip install rasa-x==0.39.3 --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
ADD . /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/start_services.sh
CMD /app/start_services.sh
```

and my start_services script is:

```
cd app/
# Start rasa server with  model
rasa x --no-prompt -p $PORT
```

I have tried running by removing $PORT as well but it doesn't work.

Note: To deploy to heroku, I created dockerfile in rasa directory where rasa was installed using rasa init and deployed it using `heroku container:push web`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You use `-port` when running Rasa. For Rasa X try `--rasa-x-port`

```
rasa x --rasa-x-port $PORT
```

Comment: Got the same error with `rasa x --no-prompt --rasa-x-port $PORT`.